# Prove $L[at + b] = at^2 + (a - b)$ is a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $L: P_1 \rightarrow P_2$, satisfy $$L[at + b] = at^2 + (a - b)t$$ for all $a,b$.

Prove that $L$ is a linear transformation.

Comment: what is the definition of a linear transformation? Write it down explicitly, and that's half the problem done.

Answer (score 1):

Consider two polynomials: $p_1=at+b$ and $p_2=ct+d$.
1. Calculate $p_1+p_2$.
2. Calculate and simplify $L(p_1+p_2)$.
3. Calculate and simplify $L(p_1)+L(p_2)$.
4. If they are equal you've done half of the work; if not, $L$ is not linear.
5. In the same way, invesigate whether $L(k p)=k L(p)$ where $p=at+b$.
6. If the equality is true then you've proven that $L$ is linear.

Comment: do you mean by calculate $p_1 + p_2$ literally adding $p_1$ and $p_2$? and what do you mean by simplify $(p_1+p_2)$?

Comment: @experiment_626 Let $p_1+p_2=(a+c)t+(b+d)$. Apply $L$ to this result; let's call this $Q$. Calculate $L(p_1)$ and $L(p_2)$ and add these two results; let's call this $R$. Compare $Q$ and $R$; they should be equal if $L$ is linear.

Comment: how do I apply $$ to $_1+_2$?, $(_1)+(_2)=(a+c)^2+(−)t+(−)t$?

Comment: When you apply $L$ to an expression $at+b$, you take $a$ (whatever $a$ is), multiply it by $t^2$ and add $b$ (whatever $b$ is).